# How to stop wkhtmltopdf.exe pop-up while running it with Python

Tags: python-3.x, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf.exe for converting html to pdf using python. The pop-up window of wkhtmltopdf.exe making it very difficult for me to work on any other things while running it. I have to convert around 200K+ files and have to work on something else simultaneously. But its really not letting me to work on anything else.

Is there a way of stopping this or running it in background?
I really appreciate your help.

PS. Sorry I am new to it, don't know any other way to stop it.

I am using wkhtmltox-0.12.2.2_msvc2013-win64 software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved the problem! made my python file executable using py2exe and used the  .py file.

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

It is no more popping the command prompt window.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `pythonw.exe` to start your script (works with `.py` and `.pyw` extensions)
2. or use `.pyw` extension for your your script (works with `python.exe` and `pythonw.exe`)

In the second case make sure the `.pyw` extension is handled by pythonw.exe (right click your `.pyw` script > `Open With` and make sure `pythonw.exe` is the default handler for `.pyw` files).

**edit**

You can also pass the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag to the `creationflags` argument if you use `subprocess.Popen` to start your executable. This flag is a flag that can be passed to the Win32 CreateProcess API and is [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Here's an example that doesn't create any console on my computer (make sure to name it with a `.pyw` extension) :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import subprocess
import urllib.parse as urlparse # import urlparse for python 2.x

CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000 # do not create a new window !

def is_url(url):
    parts = urlparse.urlsplit(url)  
    return parts.scheme and parts.netloc

def main(url, output):
    print(url, output)
    if not is_url(url):
        return -1

    proc = subprocess.Popen(["wkhtmltopdf.exe", url, output],
        creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW)

    proc.wait()
    return proc.returncode


if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = "https://www.example.com"
    output = r"c:\tmp\example.pdf"

    rval = main(url, output)

    sys.exit(rval)
```

Comment: I have already done this and checked that the default compiler is pythonw.exe. But still its not working.  I am using wkhtmltox-0.12.2.2_msvc2013-win64.exe software and then passed the location of this to the configuration file of pdfkit. Do you have any idea whats going on or what could be the reason why its not working?

Comment: @user3780390 : I added a code sample with a flag (`CREATE_NO_WINDOW`) to pass to `subprocess.popen`. Obviously this only works on windows. This works on my test computer (Win 8.1).